# Remapping ctrl-k has a delay

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to use the mapping

```
nnoremap <C-k> :bprev<CR>
```

However, whenever I press `ctrl-k`, there is a second delay before anything happens. When I use a different key combination, like ctrl-j, everything works fine.

Any idea why this happens and how this can be solved?

Comment: You should host your `.vimrc` somewhere and give a link here so someone can look at the origin of the problem. But of the top of my head I think there is another mapping <C-k> something so that when you press <C-k> it waits and sees if you press another key. Find and disable that keymapping and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yep, I had a `<c-k><c-o>` mapping. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another mapping <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>something</kbd> so that when you press <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, it waits and sees if you press another key. Find and disable that keymapping and you should be good to go.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the `timeout` and `timeoutlen` settings?